# Is it possible to deactivate file locking in cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to run the following commands side by side

```
cargo watch "check"

cargo watch "build"
```

I want to run `cargo watch build` in the background and use `cargo watch check` to look at the error messages.

The problem is that `cargo watch check` always runs after `cargo watch build` and then also needs to wait on the file lock

```
cargo check
    Blocking waiting for file lock on build directory
```

I don't think that a file lock would be required for cargo check. Is it possible to disable file locking in cargo?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just run `cargo watch build` and get the error message from that?

Comment: @Aurora0001 If you save faster than a build then you have to wait for the build to complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't think that a file lock would be required for cargo check.

I can think of in one reason: [build scripts](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html). A build script can generate files that are included in the crate, checking the crate without generating the files would probably produce errors. Running 2 instances of a build script in parallel is not a good idea (conflicting file writes, etc), so the locking is required.

---

> I want to run the following commands side by side

You have two options:

1. Sequential: install [`cargo-do`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-do) and run

   ```
   cargo watch "do check, build"
   ```

this will first run `cargo check` and then `cargo build` (if `cargo check` did not find an error).

2. Parallel: change the [`target-dir`](http://doc.crates.io/config.html#configuration-keys) for  one of the two cargo commands:

   ```
   CARGO_TARGET_DIR=/tmp cargo watch check
   ```