# cargo always starts with " Blocking waiting for file lock on build directory"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I recently installed rustup on my Windows machine and incorporated it into Atom as my editor. Everything works fine, but as soon as I do a `cargo run` on my project, the first thing that Cargo says is:

```
 Blocking waiting for file lock on build directory
```

This blocks the whole process for about a minute before the actual compile and run starts. As far as I remember this did not happen before (I use Cargo under OS X but without rustup).

Is there any way to disable this or at least reduce the timeout?

Comment: Perhaps you use an Atom plugin that runs `cargo build` to check the syntax? If it is the case, this is the issue because you cannot run `cargo` twice at the same time.

Comment: Oh yes, that is a possible solution. I'm using the tokamak plugin and - as far as I know - it does syntax checking using cargo. Thanks for the hint. I'll look furhter into this direction.

Comment: @antoyo: Sounds like an answer

Answer (score 7):

The `tokamak` Atom plugin runs `cargo` commands. Since you cannot run `cargo` twice at the same time, you get this notice.

I don't think there is something you can do, unless waiting for the compiler to speed up.

Perhaps playing with the options like `save_buffers_before_run` in `tokamak.toml` could make a difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38643019/155423 — use a different Cargo directory for tokamak and console.

Comment: After quite some time that I spent with the settings of Atom, I finally found that there was a second plugin (rust-linter) that has obviously been installed along with tokamak. And this plugin has a settting named "use cargo". After unchecking this option, I don't get the block any longer :-)))) Thank you all for your hints that finally pointed me into the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

Today I facing the same problem, and this command works for me:

```
rm -rf ~/.cargo/.package-cache
```

Once you run the code, just run `cargo build`