# How difficult is it to allow parallel compilation of code with the Rust stable and nightly channels?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The default file-tree created by Cargo allows parallel compilation of release and debug builds as they are located in their own directories; `target/release` and `target/debug`, respectively.

How difficult is it to also allow parallel compilation of `stable`/`nightly`-compiler. For example using the directories

- `target/debug/stable`
- `target/debug/nightly`

I am aware it can be done with jails/containers, but I was hoping for a somewhat more Cargo-ish solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Modern Rust

I believe that your *main* problem of rebuilding dependencies no longer exists:

```
$ cargo +nightly build
    Updating crates.io index
   Compiling either v1.5.0
   Compiling itertools v0.8.0
   Compiling example v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/example)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 5.87s
$ cargo +stable build
   Compiling either v1.5.0
   Compiling itertools v0.8.0
   Compiling example v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/example)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.67s
$ cargo +nightly build
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.17s
$ cargo +stable build
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.16s
```

I *believe* that this is a side-effect of the work done for incremental compilation: the compiler version (or something equivalent) is used as part of the hashing algorithm used for build artifacts. Thus, artifacts from multiple toolchains can coexist.

This does *not* cover the final artifact, which has a fixed name and will be overridden. Keep on reading if you really need to keep both in parallel.

## Original answer

As explained in [Is it possible to deactivate file locking in cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38640858/155423), you can set the environment variable `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` for each channel you are interested in:

```
$ CARGO_TARGET_DIR=$PWD/stable rustup run stable cargo build
   Compiling many v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/many)
    Finished debug [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.89 secs
$ CARGO_TARGET_DIR=$PWD/nightly rustup run nightly cargo build
   Compiling many v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/many)
    Finished debug [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.62 secs
$ ./stable/debug/many
Hello, world!
$ ./nightly/debug/many
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: @PureW Not worth a full answer, but I have a [`test-matrix.py`](https://github.com/DanielKeep/rust-script-toolbox/blob/master/test-matrix.py) script that does this for (simple) Travis CI configs.

Comment: Regarding your edited answer: Using CARGO_TARGET_DIR to specify a separate dir for clippy still seems to avoid recompilation.